# Regex - extract word inside < > brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract an email address from a string like

`John Smith <jsmith@email.com>`

I just need the email address in the < > brackets.

Here is what I have tried so far, but I'm not very good with regex and it doesn't seem to be working, can anyone help?

```
import re
sender = str(message.sender)
p = re.search(r"\<(\w+)\>", sender)
logging.info(p.group(1))
```

Comment: You can use: `re.search(r"<([^>]+)>", sender)`

Comment: Try this    /<([^>]*)/

Comment: If you only want the email (not the `<>`) you can modify @anubhava's regex to `(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "John Smith <jsmith@email.com>"   
email = re.findall('<(.*?)>', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'jsmith@email.com'
```

Or, a more email-specific solution:

```
email = re.findall('(?<=\<)\w+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]+(?=\>)', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'jsmith@email.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your regex is : `"\<(\w+)\>"`
You do not actually need to escape the `<>`, so it becomes: `"<(\w+)>"`
`\w` matches letters, numbers and the underschore `'_'`. In an e-mail address there are other characters as well.

You have two options: Either just accept anything inside the `<>` with a regex like `"<(.*)>"` or actually parse an e-mail address.

A simple regex for that would be `"<\S+@\S+>"` (non-whitespace characters followed by `@` followed by non-whitespace characters.

Restricting ourselves to the more commonly used characters, we can write: `"<[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+>` This still permits certain illegal e-mail addresses because I have kept it fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative character set:

```
import re
s = "John Smith <jsmith@email.com>"   
email = re.findall('<([^>])>', s)[0]
```

That matches anything thats not a `>` character, so everything thats in the angular brackets.